# Why is streaming concatenation illegal with ternary conditional assignments?

Tags: system-verilog

The following code results in an error:

```
logic [7:0] data;
logic [7:0] data_reversed;

assign data_reverse = reverse ? { << {data  }} : data;
```

> xmvlog: *E,SCXALC (../rtl/test.v,53|36): Streaming concatenation
> expression illegal in this context [LRM 11.4.14]

I do not think it is related to my simulator anyway (Cadence's xrun 18), as per the error message. I checked the mentioned LRM, and I think the requirement for this error comes from 11.4.14 (IEEE 1800-2017, page 275):

> It shall be an error to use a streaming_concatenation as an operand in
> an expression without first casting it to a bit-stream type

I'm not sure I am looking at the right place, and what does "casting it to a bit-stream type" mean? It does not make sense to me.  I am surprised this is an error, and I can't think of any reason why a simple conditional operator should result in an error.

An if-else conditional works just fine:

```
always @ (*)
if (reverse)
data_reversed = { << {data  }};
else 
data_reversed = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that cadence implements it to the letter of the LRM. Others do not. In my opinion it is an LRM bug, but

> A streaming_concatenation (as specified in Syntax 11-4) shall be used either as the target of an assignment,
> or as the source of an assignment, or as the operand of a bit-stream cast, or as a stream_expression in another
> streaming_concatenation. Use of streaming_concatenation as the target of an assignment, and the
> associated unpack operation, is described in 11.4.14.3.

> It shall be an error to use a streaming_concatenation as an operand in an expression without first casting it to
> a bit-stream type. When a streaming_concatenation is used as the source of an assignment, the target of that
> assignment shall be either a data object of bit-stream type or a streaming_concatenation.

So, ternary operator does not fit the above. But you are supposed to be able to use a cast to a bit-stream type, as in the following example:

```
  logic [7:0] data;
  logic [7:0] data_reversed;
  logic reverse;
  typedef logic[7:0] data_t;
  assign data_reverse = reverse ? data_t'({ << {data  }}) : data;
```

The above seems to work in cadence, as well in other compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The streaming concatenation is legal, but the LRM has an ambiguity about the context of operand used inside the streaming operator. (See [0003342](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=3342))

If you had

```
logic [7:0] data1;
logic [8:0] data2;
logic [8:0] data_reversed;

assign data_reverse = reverse ? { << {data1  }} : data2;
```

The LRM is not clear if the operand `data1` should get extended by one extra bit before (context-determind) or after (self-determined) applying the streaming operator. But most people on the committee seem to agree that the only reasoanble choice is self-determined. But one vendor chose not to allow it until the LRM was fixed.

Comment: Don't get it. Why should it get extended by one bit if the streaming concatenation is just doing a bit-reverse?

Comment: Because normally operands get extended before operators operate. But there are exceptions, like operands inside a concatenation.